# Define model with ipred package

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I work with the `ipred` package and use the `errorest` function to estimate the 10 fold cross validated error. But I want to specify the used model, beacuse I do not know what is done by using the predefined model, by setting model = svm.

```
require(ipred)
require(e1071)
  cv.error.svm =  errorest(y~ ., data=data, model=svm, estimator = "cv")
```

How can I define the svm function as shown in the help (?svm) as shown below?

```
svm(x, y = NULL, scale = TRUE, type = NULL, kernel =
"radial", degree = 3, gamma = if (is.vector(x)) 1 else 1 / ncol(x),
coef0 = 0, cost = 1, nu = 0.5,...)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Inside `errorest`, instead of entering parameter `model = svm`, try entering parameter `model = my.model` and then define `my.model` as `my.model = svm` (etc. etc)... according to e1071. Hope this helps!